# Faça um programa que receba como parâmetros uma cadeia de caracteres e um caractere a ser buscado e informe o índice da última ocorrência do caractere

Tags: java

Estou preso nessa parte e não consigo mais pensar o que fazer pra progredir.
Tenho pouco tempo de programação, o que posso fazer a partir daqui?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma boa prática no StackOverFlow é mandar código utilizando o próprio editor de texto do site (como no código abaixo), e não em imagem! Sobre sua pergunta:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String palavra = "abacate";
    char buscar = 'c';
    int indice = -1;
    for(int i=0;i<palavra.length();i++) {
      char atual = palavra.charAt(i);
      if(atual == buscar) indice = i;
    }
    if(indice != -1) System.out.println("Indice: "+indice);
    else System.out.println("Char nao encontrado!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Adaptei o meu programa com as suas dicas e consegui agora, e também seguirei sua dica da forma de mandar o código, muito obrigado por ambos!

Answer (score 0):

Tente  depois que fecha o for o seguinte código: `System.out.println("O último número é: " + n);`